# Invalid argument: latitude. Should be of type: number (file Code.gs, line 22) - Googel Ads Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, google-ads-api

I am currently trying to import latitude and longitude values from a sheet, into my Google ads campaign through a script that looks like this:

```
function main() {
  var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17w74flZ3AD7r7wIbAoYYkffUuJfxGB0-a9lhjBStzW4/edit#gid=0';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A:E").getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    if (i == 0) {
      continue;  
    }

    var [CampaignName, latitude, longitude, radius, unit] = data[i];

    if (CampaignName == "") {
      break;
    }
    else {
      var campaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns()
        .withCondition("CampaignName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE '" + CampaignName +"'")
        .get();
      while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
        var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
        campaign.addProximity(latitude, longitude, radius, unit);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when running the script, I keep getting the error "*Invalid argument: latitude. Should be of type: number (file Code.gs, line 22)*" What am I doing wrong?
(also the sheet link is open for anyone, and its a back up so no worries).

Comment: maybe latitude is *not* a number ? `campaign.addProximity(+latitude, longitude, radius, unit);` should coerce that

Comment: convert that to a number with expression `+latitude`

Answer (score 0):

Filter and format the data properly, with this should be enough:

```js
function main() {
  var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17w74flZ3AD7r7wIbAoYYkffUuJfxGB0-a9lhjBStzW4/edit#gid=0';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
//Note you get only relevant data ranges
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
//Now we got only non blank cells
  for (i in data) {
    if (i == 0) {
      continue;  
    }

    var [CampaignName, latitude, longitude, radius, unit] = data[i];

// Parse strings to float
    latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
    longitude = parseFloat(longitude);
    radius = parseFloat(radius);
// End of data conversion

    if (CampaignName == "") {
      break;
    }
    else {
      var campaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns()
        .withCondition("CampaignName CONTAINS_IGNORE_CASE '" + CampaignName +"'")
        .get();
      while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
        var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
        campaign.addProximity(latitude, longitude, radius, unit);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've added two things:

- This [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) function gets only non trivial data, so you are not getting a lot of blank rows.

I've kept your `if(CampaignName == "")` condition to avoid errors in case you have a blank row in between your data rows.

- Second one is [parseFloat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp), it converts your string to numbers and solves your initial problem.

As a tip:

Formating your spreadsheet numeric cells as numbers help on the importation process, because you'll import them as such, and you won't need to convert it.